# C++ Int to String by using ostringstream or stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, ostringstream

I've been using `stringstream` to convert `Integer` to `String`, but then I realized same operation can be done with `ostringstream`.

When I use `.str()` what is the difference between them? Also, is there more efficient way to convert integers to strings?

Sample code:

```
//using ostringstream

ostringstream s1;
int i=100;
s1<<i;
string str_i=s1.str();
cout<<str_i<<endl;

//using stringstream

stringstream s2;
int i2=100;
s2<<i2;
string str_i2=s2.str();
cout<<str_i2<<endl;
```

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292107/whats-the-difference-between-istringstream-ostringstream-and-stringstream-w fnprintf does the same job faster but it depends on your code ofcourse.

Comment: C++11 has [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @cateof Sorry, I didn't see that post.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley whoaaaa C++11 blows my mind again. I thought all we got was string -> int with `stoi` and friends, but I didn't know we have the other way too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a third that you didn't mention, `istringstream`, which you can't use (well you could but it would be different, you can't `<<` to an `istringstream`).

`stringstream` is both an `ostringstream` and an `istringstream` - you can `<<` and `>>` both ways, in and out.

With `ostringstream`, you can *only* go in with `<<`, and you cannot go out with `>>`.

There isn't really a difference, you can use either way to convert strings to integers. If you want to do it the fastest way possible, I think `boost::lexical_cast` has that title, or you could use the `itoa` function which may be faster than `stringstream`, but you lose the advantages of C++ and the standard library if you use `itoa` (you have to use C-strings, etc).

Also, as Benjamin Lindley informed us, C++11 has the ultramagical [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: Thank you so much!, I'll definitely try the methods you mentioned.

Comment: I think `boost::lexical_cast` is great, but it's probably not the best in terms of run-time performance. It's just a wrapper around the `ostringstream` technique.  See [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm).

Comment: @FredLarson I thought boost did some specialisation for integers or something that made it faster. Maybe I just misread something somewhere.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Oh, perhaps. That would be a great idea.

Comment: @FredLarson, I don't think that's necessarily true anymore.  As of [Boost 1.48.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp), there is *way* more code in there than just a simple wrapper around a `stringstream`.

Comment: [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/) has the title of "fastest", but it comes with a not-insignificant compile-time cost. Boost.LexicalCast just wraps around `snprintf`.

Comment: Boost.LexicalCast's number to string conversions are okay, but their string to number conversions are pretty terrible.

Comment: std::string str(itoa(numberVar,tempChars,10));