# Fstream contain all the content of ofstream and ifstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Why do we use `std;:ofstream` for output and `std::ifstream` for input if it is possible to use `std::fstream` for both?

Comment: I think he is asking if you can just use something like `fstream The_Old_In_And_Out;` and have it behave as both an input and output stream

Comment: @Chemistpp: Wait, that is a valid interpretation of his question too.  Darn.  Rolling back my edit...

Comment: It likely would have taken less effort to simply read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) than go through the trouble of posting here.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the fstream, ofstream and ifstream library. I can get the ofstream and ifstream clases from the fstream library, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the similar case as with stringstream, istringstream and ostringsstream ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292107/whats-the-difference-between-istringstream-ostringstream-and-stringstream-w)).

Usually you don't both read and write from the same stream, so using ifstream and ofstream is easier as you don't have to bother about the stream state and stream positions (as is the case with fstream).