# Browse words within a line in C++ after getline

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get each words of a line extracted with getline?

for example, with this example as a "test.txt" file:

```
18407111  2018-07-05 00:04:02  MHAM  EIDW  42  S1REB  RYR5GW  3726  JNEIE  837B  Datum  RYR  IFR  Undefined  1  1  2018-07-05  00:15:38  2018-07-05  00:22:56  111  extended
0.0  113416.9  479798.5  -0.2  3.6  0.0
```

I can get the first line in a loop with getline(file,line) but from this line, i want to browse each "words" that are in it starting with "18407111".

I tried something but i only managed to get the first word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

main() {
    int info[100][6] = {0};
    int  i =0, j;
    std::ifstream file {"test.txt"};
    std::string line;
    std::string word;
    while (getline(file,line))
    {
        word = line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
        std::cout << word << "\n";
        std::stoi(word)>> info[i][0];
        i++;
        return 0;
           }
    }
```

I need those data separate in order to work with it like:

```
18407111
2018
07
05
00
04
02
MHAM
etc...
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Your question is not about any of those specific C++ versions, but about generic C++. I've removed the excessive, not applicable tags.

Comment: Why use `getline` in the first place? Why not just `while (file >> word)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk because when i use file >> word i don't manage to get all the data afterwards "0.0 113416.9 479798.5 -0.2 3.6 0.0" to store them in an array because it either skips the first or the last value with the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `stringstream` and read the word.

```
while (getline(file,line))  {
   std::istringstream ss(line);
   std::string word;
   while (ss >> word) {
         std::cout << "This is the word: " << word << "\n";
   }
}
```

but you can just `while (file >> word)` straight anyway.

Comment: Consider using `std::istringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`

Comment: [What's the difference between istringstream, ostringstream and stringstream? / Why not use stringstream in every case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3292107/3422102) -- I was curious too. Crux, `i/o...` provides clear expression of intent, and `stringstream` itself would be larger and slightly less efficient (emphasis on *slightly* - though no time or memory comparisons are provided in the linked question)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Shouldn't it be `while (ss>>line)` instead?    I can't use file>>word because when i store data it can skips words

Comment: @Random yes, it should be!